# What is the solution of the two point distance?

Tags: c++

The problem is about calculating the distance between two points, when I run the program I get this error message:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable `y2` is being used without being initialized.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double x1,y1,x2,y2;
  cin >> x1,y1;
  cin >> x2,y2;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << pow((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1),0.5); 

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: The comma operator does not do what you think is does in this context. Use `cin >> x2 >> y2`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
cin>>x1,y1; cin>>x2,y2;
```

to

```
cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
```

As @CaptainObvlious said:

> The `,` operator does not do what you think it does in this context.

`cin` and `cout` support *chaining* (You can input a number of variables using a single statement, by extending the statement using `>>` for `cin`, `<<` for `cout`).

Comment: He is correct, chaining is supported in C++ for '>>' istream operator and '<<' ostream operator.

Comment: @SameerSawla Thanks for the term *chaining*, I was desperately searching for the right term to express this answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double coords[4];
  int coordsCounter = 0;

  while (coordsCounter < 4) {
    cin >> coords[coordsCounter]; //here you must filter the input
    coordsCounter++;
  }

  cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << pow(pow((coords[2] - coords[0]), 2) + pow((coords[3] - coords[1]), 2), 0.5);

  return 0;
}
```